# Getting Last Day of Previous Month in Oracle Function

Tags: database, oracle, function, date-arithmetic

I need a function in `Oracle` like this.

When i giving a parameter a simple date. Then function should getting me last day of the previous month.

Example:

```
FunctionName(10.02.2011) Result should be 31.01.2011

FunctionName(21.03.2011) Result should be 28.02.2011

FunctionName(31.07.2011) Result should be 30.06.2011 (Even date is last day of month)
```

How can i do that? By the way, i never use `Oracle` .

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(yourdate,-1))
```

Comment: These functions have been part of standard Oracle for a couple of decades.

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to the other answers here, you can also find the last day of the previous month by getting the day before the first day of this month

```
SELECT trunc(your_date, 'MM')-1 as new_date from your_table
```

I would probably still recommend using `last_day(add_months(xxx,-1))` but just showing an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

`select LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1)) from dual`;

format resulting date as you like (I'll leave that one for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

With this you can also get the last BUSINESS DAY of the previous month, or any other month changing the -1.

```
SELECT (trunc(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)), 'iw') + 4) from dual
```