# Last day of month joined to second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the last day of the previous month and then join this to another table to return the year/month column that the date relates to but I'm struggling to achieve what I want.

I have tried:

```
SELECT b.yrmonth, LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)) DT 
FROM dual a
INNER JOIN D_DAY b on DT = b.DT
```

The year month just returns everything in the table rather than just one row so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Last Day of Previous Month in Oracle Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957224/getting-last-day-of-previous-month-in-oracle-function)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not a duplicate. The OP knows how to get the last day of the previous month; the issue is with the join condition.

Comment: An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join with `dual` table. You can simply add your condition in the`where` clause:

```
select *
from D_DAY b
where TRUNC(b.DT) = TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))
```

and cast the `date` (with time)  as `date` because `LAST_DAY` function returns `date` (with time component and if you want to check the date, you need to cast it before.

Comment: You do not need to use `TO_DATE` on `DATE` data types. `LAST_DAY()` returns a `DATE` data type and `TO_DATE` takes a string input so Oracle has to do an implict `TO_CHAR` and is effectively doing `TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( LAST_DAY( ... ), NLS_DATE_FORMAT ), 'DD-MON-YYYY' )`. This will fail if the user changes the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter so that it does not match the explicit format model (or if the query is run internationally when the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is likely to change between countries).

Comment: I added the cast because LAST_DAY() is returning a TIMESTAMP data type; if you try to check it, this returns false:
`LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)) = to_date('30/09/2017', 'dd/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: It is not returning a timestamp - it is returning a date with a time component (the Oracle `DATE` data type has year/month/day/hour/minute/second components). If the time component is not required then use `TRUNC` to truncate it back to midnight. Using `TO_DATE` and relying on an implicit `TO_CHAR` is the wrong solution.

Comment: Ok, I agree that TRUNC is better, but still you need to cast the date (with time) :) however thank you for your explanation.

Comment: `'DD-MON-YYY'` isn't a valid format model for `trunc(datetime)`. It needs to be one of these: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm

Comment: Ok, I forgot to remove it. Thank you @WilliamRobertson

Answer (score 1):

Your query is effectively:

```
SELECT b.yrmonth,
       'some constant masking b.DT' DT 
FROM   dual a
       INNER JOIN
       D_DAY b
       on ( b.DT = b.DT ) -- Always true
```

You do not need to join the `DUAL` table and need to filter your table in the `WHERE` clause.

If the `DT` date column has varying time components:

```
SELECT yrmonth, dt
FROM   D_DAY
WHERE  DT >= TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)))
AND    DT <  TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM');
```

*(Which will allow the database to use indexes on the `DT` column)*

or, if your `DT` column always has dates with the time component at midnight:

```
SELECT yrmonth, dt
FROM   D_DAY
WHERE  DT = TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)));
```